# Mass Item-level Update for SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services Portal

Tags: sql-server, permissions, reportingservices-2005

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services site that I can get to by https://localserver/reports Now when for setting permissions on each folder and report item or datasource item in that folder I have to click on the "properties" then "security" of the item, and then assign the appropriate permissions. It's just that there are hundreds of items I need to modify the security to pretty much the same thing. Is there a way I can do a mass update of the Item-level security roles?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160854(SQL.90).aspx) up.

Raj